# Importing two modules with same name

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to import two modules having same name i.e

```
import {Input, Icon} from 'native-base'
```

and

```
import {Input, Button} from 'react-native-elements'
```

How can I import and use both of them in my JSX? is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `as` when importing

```js
import {Input as InputBase, Icon} from 'native-base'
import {Input, Button} from 'react-native-elements'
```

Comment: Drusto, thanks for answer. 
Slightly edited the question. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Perfect, Will mark it answered after 10 minutes (minimum time SOF take to allow you to answer)

Comment: @Drusto you beat me just in time! +1

Comment: Glad it helped! Keep hacking!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use import as:

```
import {Input as NativeBaseInput, Icon } from 'native-base'
import {Input, Button} from 'react-native-elements'
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for answer. Slightly edited the question. Can you update your answer?